Need to write templatefile function in yaml format
Below is the template file function written in tf format
resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "sfn_state_machine_for_slack_workflow_sm" {
  name = Step_Fucntion_name_for_slack_workflow_SM
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.Step_Function_Role.arn
  definition = templatefile("${path.module}/defination_slack_workflow_sm.tftpl", {Lambdaarn_OF_CallbackSlack="${var.LambdaARN_OF_CallbackSlack}"})
}

Would like to write above tf code into yaml format spefically defination field
Search through stack overflow for the solution and even terraform documentation

And what is in the template file you currently have?

its a step function defination file

Sure, and can you add that to the question as well? Are there any errors?

I tried to create the resources when above code written in tf file, it got created successfully.
But when i tried to convert the tf file to yaml format, its getting failed. So i believe i am not able to convert the file tf to yaml correctly. hence asking here

Which file do you want to convert to YML?
